# JSON error in Java while trying to access google api

Tags: java, json, google-api

The following is a test code, in which I am trying to post some query via google api, the api should send the response in json parseable string. 
When I print the string I clearly see the entities such as url, but when I try to get these entities from JSON Object, I get the error.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.json.JSONObject;



public class test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {
            // The request also includes the userip parameter which provides the end
            // user's IP address. Doing so will help distinguish this legitimate
            // server-side traffic from traffic which doesn't come from an end-user.
            URL url = new URL(
                    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=lahore");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();


            String line;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                System.out.println(line);

            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            System.out.println(jsonObject);

            String url1 = (String) jsonObject.get("url");
            System.out.println(url1);


        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

it throws following exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["url"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:459)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:540)
    at test.main(test.java:37)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: U seem to have multilingual characters, try this BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

Comment: Hi Nitin, when i convert the string to json object, some how it ignores half of the string and starts from the entity cursor. all the previous entities are being missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining the json string:

You can't directly get the "url", to get "url" you would need to do below once you read the stream into the StringBuilder:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
JSONObject responseData = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("responseData");
JSONArray results = (JSONArray)responseData.get("results");
for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++)
{
     JSONObject urlObject  = (JSONObject)results.get(i);
     System.out.println(urlObject.get("url"));
}
```